# An inequality concerning sums of sequences of positive real numbers and their reciprocals

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Suposse we have two non-decreasing sequences of strictly positive real numbers $$0< a_1\le a_2\le \cdots \le a_n \ \text{ and } 0< b_1\le b_2\le \cdots \le b_n$$
and suppose that $$\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^k b_i \ \forall k=1,\dots , n.$$
Does this imply that $$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{a_i} \le \sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1{b_i}$$
is true?

I tried several classic inequalities but I failed to prove it.

Edit: Edited to correct a mistake.

Comment: $f(t) = 1/t$ is convex, so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @MartinR Thank you, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I explain an elementary solution based in the proof of [Karamata's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karamata%27s_inequality) as suggested by Martin_R in the comments, without using it.

Recall we have real numbers $$0< a_1\le a_2\le \cdots \le a_n \ \text{ and } 0< b_1\le b_2\le \cdots \le b_n$$
and suppose that $$A_k:=\sum_{i=1}^k a_i \ge \sum_{i=1}^k b_i =:B_k $$ for all $k=1,\dots , n$.

Consider $$\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\frac 1{b_i}-\frac 1{a_i} \right) = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{a_ib_i}\left(a_i-b_i\right)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{1}{a_ib_i}\left((A_i-A_{i-1})-(B_i-B_{i-1})\right)=$$
$$= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \left(\frac{1}{a_ib_i}-\frac{1}{a_{i+1}b_{i+1}}\right)\left(A_i-B_i\right)+\frac{1}{a_nb_n}\left(A_n-B_n\right) \ge 0$$
since $(A_i-B_i)\ge 0$ for all $i\ge 0$ for hypothesis, as well as $$\left(\frac{1}{a_ib_i}-\frac{1}{a_{i+1}b_{i+1}}\right)\ge 0$$
since $a_{i+1}b_{i+1} \ge a_{i}b_{i+1}\ge a_{i}b_{i} $.

Answer (score 1):

No.  For example, $1 + 5 \ge 2 + 4 = 6$ but $1/1 + 1/5 > 1/2 + 1/4$.

Comment: I see. Now I found I made a mistake with I have asked... Sorry